# Table Controller - Azure Mobile Services .Net backend not returning

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile Service with .Net backend with a table controller on the service side. 
I can query the table on the service webpage (the default "try it" pages) and get the table data back but in my Windows Phone client it gets stuck on the statement.

```
ContactTable = AzureClient.GetTable<Contact>();
var res = await ContactTable.Select(c => c.Owner == _userId).ToCollectionAsync();
obj = res; // It never gets to this line
```

Contact definition (the same as the service side):

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Contact
    {
    public Contact()
    {
        ImageTags = new HashSet<ImageTag>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long Owner { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ImageTag> ImageTags { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Can you check your query in Fiddler?  It's also possible that you have too many records in your result set, and the ToCollectionAsync() call is the problem.

Comment: The issue was with threads. I still have not found a solution though. My main thread that took care of logging into azure service can use the APIs but the worker threads don't get the call back after the service side execution (They call the API with Post/Get, Service executes the requests and returns the result, they don't get notified no one wakes them up).

Comment: Have you made sure the data you get back in the "try it" tester can be deserialized into your client object? Chances are good based on what you describe that an error is being raised but lost because of the async call. Do you have the actual calls shown above wrapped in a try/catch? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Somehow it's working now. I have no idea what made it work.It could be a bug on Azure that was fixed.